# Appropriate values for -Infinity & Infinity in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

In one case, we have to store values for +infinity & -infinity in a Postgres DB?

What should be appropriate value that should be considered?

If there is not one, then please suggest the best suitable alternative.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can actually use `+infinity` and `-infinity` for `FLOAT4` and `FLOAT8` (i.e. `float` and `double precision`) data types, and for timestamps.

```
regress=> SELECT FLOAT8 '+infinity', FLOAT8 '-infinity';
  float8  |  float8   
----------+-----------
 Infinity | -Infinity
(1 row)
```

For other types, either use a separate column, use the minimum/maximum values for the type, or (where logically appropriate) use null.

Comment: In PG11, `+infinity` (explicit **+**) is invalid syntax for timestamps, but works with numeric types. For example, `SELECT '+infinity'::timestamp;` is an error, but `infinity` is valid syntax. I'm on OpenBSD and my *strtod* accepts "+infinity". Huh?

Comment: SELECT '+infinity'::numeric;
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: "+infinity"

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the string `'infinity'` or `'-infinity'` into a **numeric/float/real/double precision** column types. However, this will be *out of range error* for **integer/bigint/smallint**.

- `'+infinity'` and `'infinity'` and `'Infinity'` are equivalent
- `'-infinity'` and `'-Infinity'` are equivalent

Some example that work ✅ :

```
INSERT INTO table
    (real_column)
VALUES ('-Infinity'::float);
```

or even

```
INSERT INTO table
    (numeric_column)
VALUES ('infinity'::numeric);
```

or

```
INSERT INTO table
    (float_column)
VALUES ('+infinity');
```

Answer (score -6):

add another column name "infinite", 1 means +infinity, -1 means -infinity
when you are checking numbers, check the column first.

this will save you a lot of time thinking about magic numbers or other stuff.

Comment: PG supports infinity natively without need for extra columns: IEEE 754 special values "infinity" and "negative infinity".