# Does PostgreSQL numeric type support infinity (and -infinity)?

Tags: r, postgresql, rpostgresql

Following on from this question and subsequent answers:
[Appropriate values for -Infinity & Infinity in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25927464/appropriate-values-for-infinity-infinity-in-postgres)

and the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/datatype-numeric.html), it seems clear that the `real` and `double precision` number types support both positive and negative infinity. However, no mention is made for the `numeric` type, except that the `range` has "no limit".

Are positive and negative infinity supported for `numeric` types (in PostgreSQL 9.5), and if so, how does one insert such values?

EDIT (as suggested by @TimBiegeleisen):
The reason this came about is because I am trying to write a numeric column from `R` to a database table. The column contains `Inf` values, but using `dbWriteTable` from `RPostgreSQL` errors with:

```
Error in postgresqlgetResult(new.con) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : 
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: "Inf"
```

In my particular case I can convert `Inf` to `NA` and write these values as `NULL`, but this doesn't work when the column contains missing values, or the `not null`  condition is imposed in the database. I suppose another thing to do would be to write an arbitrarily large number.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`NUMERIC` does not support +-infinity, though it does support NaN. That's rather an unfortunate limitation. Addressing it would probably require changing the on-disk binary format of `numeric` which could be challenging...

```
craig=> SELECT NUMERIC 'NaN';
 numeric 
---------
     NaN
(1 row)

craig=> SELECT NUMERIC '-inf';
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: "-inf"
LINE 1: SELECT NUMERIC '-inf';
                       ^
craig=> SELECT NUMERIC '+inf';
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: "+inf"
LINE 1: SELECT NUMERIC '+inf';

craig=> SELECT NUMERIC '+infinity';
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: "+infinity"
LINE 1: SELECT NUMERIC '+infinity';
                       ^
craig=> SELECT NUMERIC 'infinity';
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: "infinity"
LINE 1: SELECT NUMERIC 'infinity';
                       ^
craig=> SELECT NUMERIC '-infinity';
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: "-infinity"
LINE 1: SELECT NUMERIC '-infinity';
```

Answer (score 11):

PostgreSQL will support numeric +inf/-inf from v14

Answer (score 1):

Floating point types have the following special values:

```
Infinity
-Infinity
NaN
```

This is the case as far back as v8.2, and is still current.

(Ref: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-numeric.html)

---

EDIT: I can see the problem you are trying to solve. Coming from a maths background, I can see why you might want for example integer values including positive and negative infinity, and NaN (for asymptotes, limits, etc). Unfortunately PostgreSQL doesn't have those values available for integers or decimal types. You *could* mock it though, by having two columns:

```
"myNumeric" NUMERIC,
"myNumericSpecialInformation" REAL
```

Then in the column `myNumericSpecialInformation` either store `NULL` if there is no special information, or store (as per requirement) `Infinity`, `-Infinity` or `NaN`, and handle population and management of these values in your application business logic.

Comment: but `numeric` is not a floating point type right? Further, it gets confusing as it says that there is no limit for the range in `numeric`, so I would assume it supports infinity?

Comment: @Alex If you check [this demo](http://rextester.com/IUUUH60599) you will see that casting an infinite float to numeric does not give the result you might expect.

Comment: oh dear. Thanks @TimBiegeleisen. So, numeric does not support infinity then.

Comment: @Alex I'm not completely certain of that, but it certainly looks like a cast from one to the other won't work.  Maybe you could update your question with why you need infinity support; there could be a workaround.

Comment: See my edited answer, which provides a workaround whilst still utilising the special values available in the float type

Comment: unfortunately numeric only supports finite numbers and i think the there's further limit of 2 billion digits.